Share a link of a video with expiration date and block download option
Is there anyway I could share a video with a link with someone with an expiration date and blocked download? I tried OneDrive but seems they require business account. I want it as cheap as possible, (20-30 bucks) so I couldn't register for OneDrive. I also tried google drive. It blocks download, but it needs an API call to Drive API which is fine but the whole video playing on Google Drive is a pain.
I was wondering if you guys could think of any other product to use that's cheap and properly plays a video regardless of the other person's email address provider and etc.?
Thanks,
